# ruamel parser error on reading special characters

Tags: ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml (0.15.37) and have a data structure like:

```
- !Message
  Name:  my message
  Messages:
  - !Message
    name: InputMsg1
    - !Variable
          Name: control_word
          Length: 8
          Type: Signed
          Unit:  %  # ruamel parser erro
```

If I read the YAML-file I get the error

> File "_ruamel_yaml.pyx", line 904, in
>   _ruamel_yaml.CParser._parse_next_event (ext/_ruamel_yaml.c:12818) ruamel.yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
>   found character that cannot start any token

If I start with any other character then no error will be generated.

```
- !Message
  Name:  my message
  Messages:
  - !Message
    name: InputMsg1
    - !Variable
          Name: control_word
          Length: 8
          Type: Signed
          Unit:  a %  # no parser erro
```

I also tried `&#37;`

Comment: You should always provide a minimal example when posting here. There is no need to include tagged data to get this error, and your indentation here is such that this is invalid YAML because of other reasons as well. You should indent data or programs by four spaces, when is not executable code (select the block and press the `{}` icon).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Next time, I will place a valid Yaml-File!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percent sign is an [indicator character](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2772075) and those cannot start plain scalars. So you will have to quote the percent sign:

```
         Unit:  "%"
```

or

```
         Unit:  '%'
```

(you can probably also make it a literal block scalar:

```
         Unit:  |
           %
```

or folding scalar, but  I don't think that is better readable).

Since `&` is an indicator character as well that will throw the same error, but you seem to (mistakingly) assume you can do HTML escapes in YAML (you can't).